# Recycler view is not showing items on Fragment (Android)

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment

I am trying to let my RecyclerView show the 'Message-rooms' items after I receive it from the server.

Currently, RecyclerView is on Fragment which is connected to BottomNavigationView.

I used 'MessageRoomAdapter' to set informations from the server response, but somehow, after successful communication, my RecyclerView shows just empty(white) screen.

Is it related to lifecycle problem?

I googled it for hours, but couldn't find answer.

MessageRoomAdapter.java

```
public class MessageRoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MessageRoomAdapter.CustomViewHolder> {

private ArrayList<MessageRoomItem> message_room_item_list;

private OnItemClickListener mListener = null;

public MessageRoomAdapter(ArrayList<MessageRoomItem> message_room_item_list) {
    this.message_room_item_list = message_room_item_list;
}

public interface OnItemClickListener {
    void onItemClick(View v, int position);
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MessageRoomAdapter.CustomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_message_room, parent, false);
    CustomViewHolder holder = new CustomViewHolder(view);

    return holder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MessageRoomAdapter.CustomViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.tv_item_message_room_idx.setText(Integer.toString(message_room_item_list.get(position).getMessage_room_idx()));
    holder.tv_item_message_user_idx.setText(Integer.toString(message_room_item_list.get(position).getUser_idx()));
    holder.tv_item_message_user_nickname.setText(message_room_item_list.get(position).getUser_nickname());
    holder.tv_item_message_message_idx.setText(Integer.toString(message_room_item_list.get(position).getMessage_idx()));
    holder.tv_item_message_content.setText(message_room_item_list.get(position).getContent());
    holder.tv_item_message_time.setText(message_room_item_list.get(position).getTime());

    holder.itemView.setTag(position);
    
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != message_room_item_list ? message_room_item_list.size() : 0);
}

public class CustomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    protected TextView tv_item_message_user_nickname;
    protected TextView tv_item_message_time;
    protected TextView tv_item_message_content;
    protected TextView tv_item_message_room_idx;
    protected TextView tv_item_message_user_idx;
    protected TextView tv_item_message_message_idx;

    public CustomViewHolder(@NonNull final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.tv_item_message_user_nickname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_message_user_nickname);
        this.tv_item_message_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_message_time);
        this.tv_item_message_content = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_message_content);
        this.tv_item_message_room_idx = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_message_room_idx);
        this.tv_item_message_user_idx = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_message_user_idx);
        this.tv_item_message_message_idx = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_item_message_message_idx);
    }
}
```

}

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity implements MainActivityView {

private long mBackKeyPressedTime = 0;
private Toast mToast;

BottomNavigationView bottom_navigation_view_main;

FragmentAgora fragmentAgora;
FragmentRestaurant fragmentRestaurant;
FragmentMessage fragmentMessage;
FragmentMyPage fragmentMyPage;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    bottom_navigation_view_main = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation_view_main);

    fragmentAgora = new FragmentAgora();
    fragmentRestaurant = new FragmentRestaurant();
    fragmentMessage = new FragmentMessage();
    fragmentMyPage = new FragmentMyPage();


    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_main, fragmentAgora).commitAllowingStateLoss();

    bottom_navigation_view_main.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) { 
                case R.id.item_agora_main: {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_main, fragmentAgora).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    return true;
                }
                case R.id.item_restaurant_main: {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_main, fragmentRestaurant).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    return true;
                }
                case R.id.item_message_main: {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_main, fragmentMessage).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    return true;
                }
                case R.id.item_mypage_main: {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_layout_main, fragmentMyPage).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                    return true;
                }

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

FragmentMessage.java

```
public class FragmentMessage extends Fragment implements FragmentMessageView{
ViewGroup viewGroup;

private ArrayList<MessageRoomItem> m_message_room_item_list;
private MessageRoomAdapter messageRoomAdapter;
private RecyclerView rv_message_box;
private LinearLayoutManager linear_layout_manager;

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_message, container, false);

    rv_message_box = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.rv_message_box_message_list);

    linear_layout_manager = new LinearLayoutManager(viewGroup.getContext());
    rv_message_box.setLayoutManager(linear_layout_manager);

    m_message_room_item_list = new ArrayList<>();
    messageRoomAdapter = new MessageRoomAdapter(m_message_room_item_list);
    rv_message_box.setAdapter(messageRoomAdapter);

    trygetMessageList();

    return viewGroup;
}

private void trygetMessageList() {

    final FragmentMessageService fragmentMessageService = new FragmentMessageService(this);
    fragmentMessageService.getMessageRoomList();
}


@Override
public void getMessageRoomListSuccess(MessageRoomResponse messageRoomResponse) {

    Toast.makeText(getContext(), messageRoomResponse.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    switch (messageRoomResponse.getCode()){
        default:
            System.out.println(messageRoomResponse.getMessage());
            loadMessageRooms(messageRoomResponse);
    }
}

public void loadMessageRooms(MessageRoomResponse messageRoomResponse){
    switch (messageRoomResponse.getCode()){
        case 100:
            int num_of_message_rooms = messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().size();

            for (int i = 0; i < num_of_message_rooms; i++){
                MessageRoomItem messageRoomItem = new MessageRoomItem();

                messageRoomItem.setMessage_room_idx(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getMessage_room_idx());
                messageRoomItem.setUser_idx(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getUser_idx());
                messageRoomItem.setUser_nickname(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getUser_nickname());
                messageRoomItem.setMessage_idx(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getMessage_idx());
                messageRoomItem.setContent(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getContent());
                messageRoomItem.setTime(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getTime());

                m_message_room_item_list.add(messageRoomItem);
            }

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

}

FragmentMessageService.java

```
public class FragmentMessageService {
private final FragmentMessageView mFragmentMessageView;
private HashMap<String, Object> mParams;

public FragmentMessageService(final FragmentMessageView fragmentMessageView) {
    this.mFragmentMessageView = fragmentMessageView;
}

public FragmentMessageService(FragmentMessageView mFragmentMessageView, HashMap<String, Object> mParams) {
    this.mFragmentMessageView = mFragmentMessageView;
    this.mParams = mParams;
}

void getMessageRoomList() {
    final FragmentMessageRetrofitInterface fragmentMessageRetrofitInterface = getRetrofit().create(FragmentMessageRetrofitInterface.class);
    fragmentMessageRetrofitInterface.getMessageRoomList(X_ACCESS_TOKEN).enqueue(new Callback<MessageRoomResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<MessageRoomResponse> call, Response<MessageRoomResponse> response) {

            final MessageRoomResponse messageRoomResponse = response.body();
            if (messageRoomResponse == null) {
                mFragmentMessageView.validateFailure(null);
                return;
            }
            mFragmentMessageView.getMessageRoomListSuccess(messageRoomResponse);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<MessageRoomResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            mFragmentMessageView.validateFailure(null);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Your code never notifies adapter about inserting items, you should avoid keeping a reference to the list in the fragment and move it inside adapter, then create a method to add items to the list and notifyItemRangeInserted.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating an empty list of `m_message_room_item_list` and setting that list to Adapter, then you are actually loading the list, but never updating the Adapter.

What you should do is create a method inside adapter like:

```
public void setList(ArrayList<MessageRoomItem> message_room_item_list) {
    this.message_room_item_list = message_room_item_list;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

and then call it in loadMessageRooms() perhaps, like:

```
public void loadMessageRooms(MessageRoomResponse messageRoomResponse){
    switch (messageRoomResponse.getCode()){
        case 100:
            int num_of_message_rooms = messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().size();

            for (int i = 0; i < num_of_message_rooms; i++){
                MessageRoomItem messageRoomItem = new MessageRoomItem();

                messageRoomItem.setMessage_room_idx(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getMessage_room_idx());
                messageRoomItem.setUser_idx(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getUser_idx());
                messageRoomItem.setUser_nickname(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getUser_nickname());
                messageRoomItem.setMessage_idx(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getMessage_idx());
                messageRoomItem.setContent(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getContent());
                messageRoomItem.setTime(messageRoomResponse.getMessageRoomResults().get(i).getTime());

                m_message_room_item_list.add(messageRoomItem);
            }

            messageRoomAdapter.setList(m_message_room_item_list);

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: I really, really appreciate for your kind explanation. I joined StackOverflow today just to ask this question. How sill I am...without notifying adapter...haha. Really thanks again.